# tab content doesn't fade out when I chose another tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using for first time bootstrap to build a website. I have been trying to make a box of diferent multimedia content that changes when the user want.

I developed this code based in bootstrap it has 2 problems:

1. The content when fade in doesn't replace the previous content, it
   positions behind the previous one.
2. The elements do not fade out when I click in another tag element.

Example below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=2">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container" id="main">
       <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
           <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#texto">Texto</a></li>
           <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#imagen">Imagen</a></li>
           <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#video">Video</a></li>
           <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#ppt">PPT</a></li>
       </ul>
       <div class="tab-content">
           <div id="texto" class="tab-pane fade in active">
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
           </div>
           <div id="imagen" class="tab-pane fade">
               <img src="27042015_logo1_600x600.jpg" width="450" height="400" alt="foto"> </div>
           </div>
           <div id="video" class="tab-pane fade out">
               <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xMSjtcNdi8I" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
           </div>
           <div id="ppt" class="tab-pane fade">
               <iframe src="http://www.slideshare.net/HubSpot/slideshelf" width="615px" height="470px" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none;" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen></iframe>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: @Kawinesh SK : Improper edit.. Missing some description!!

Comment: @Pugazh what i missed ?

Comment: I saw the code missing in previous edit. It's fixed now.

Comment: @Kawinesh Tab not Tav correct it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/8vLLhny0/1/)** works fine..

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTab">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#texto" aria-controls="texto" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Texto</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#imagen" aria-controls="imagen" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Imagen</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#video" aria-controls="video" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Video</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#ppt" aria-controls="ppt" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">PPT</a></li> 
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="texto"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p></div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="imagen"><img src="27042015_logo1_600x600.jpg" width="450" height="400" alt="foto"></div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="video"> <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xMSjtcNdi8I" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="ppt"> <iframe src="http://www.slideshare.net/HubSpot/slideshelf" width="615px" height="470px" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none;" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen></iframe></div>
</div>
```

Refer this **[Site](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)** for more info..

Comment: Can I ask why do you use the "aria-controls" attribute?

Comment: @gonzalomr **Sets or retrieves the list of elements that are controlled by the current element**